# Visual Studio Code remove tag highlight

Tags: tags, visual-studio-code, highlight

I want to remove the highlighting of a tag when my cursor is on it. For example Visual Studio Code shows a paragraph tag like this: `[<]p[>]` where I want it to show like this `<p>`. See image for an example.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnU8e.png)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your settings.json put:

> // Highlight matching brackets when one of them is selected.
>
> "editor.matchBrackets": false,

That will stop the behavior you see, but will do it for all supported languages (so also javascript for example).  You can change that setting for only html by :

```
"[html]": {
   "editor.matchBrackets": false
}
```

Comment: Thanks a thousand Mark!

Comment: Note that this is not a perfect solution, because when using html in php files, angle brackets are still highlighted

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this has changed since the other answers were posted:

`Value is not accepted. Valid values: "always", "near", "never".(1)`

Use this instead:

`"editor.matchBrackets": "never"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"editor.selectionHighlight": false
```

Ref -> https://www.samundra.com.np/disable-annoying-highlight-in-visual-studio-code/1666