# remove white box html tag trackers in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

how do I remove or disable the white box that tracks tag signs "<" and ">" ??

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47200387/visual-studio-code-remove-tag-highlight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to your user settings:

```
"[html]": {
   "editor.matchBrackets": false
}
```